# Retrieve data sent from Angular to php program?

Tags: php, angularjs, post

Here is my function AngularJS

```
'use strict';

 app
.factory('userProvider', function ($rootScope , $http) {

  function logIn(user) {
    var url='http://127.0.0.1:100/suitecrm/service/rest.php';

    /*$http.post(url,user)
      .success(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
        alert(user['username']);  //data is displayed normally here
        alert(user['password']);  //data is displayed normally here
      });
    */

    $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:100/suitecrm/service/rest.php',
      //data: 'username: user['username'] , password: user['password'] }
      data: { username: user['username'] , password: user['password']}

    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
      console.log(response);

    }, function errorCallback(response) {
      // called asynchronously if an error occurs
      // or server returns response with an error status.
    });
  }

  return {
    logIn: logIn
  }
});
```

I want to retrieve my two variable username and password in my file rest.php.
Here is the code where i get username and password

```
$username =$_POST['username'];
$password =$_POST['password'];
```

But when i open the console an error is displayed : username & password not defined in rest.php so how can i retrieve data in my file rest.php correctly.

Comment: This is the error in the console :

<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: username in <b>C:\Users\hp1\Desktop\Stage\SugarCrm Thinline\suitecrm\service\rest.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: password in <b>C:\Users\hp1\Desktop\Stage\SugarCrm Thinline\suitecrm\service\rest.php</b> on line <b>4</b><br />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that unless you are submitting via a `form method="POST"` you need to read/parse the raw input stream.

Try with:

```
$request = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

You can put this at the start of your PHP script.  `$request` will then be an `stdClass` object with the data as properties.

```
$username = $request->username;
$password = $request->password;
```

Alternatively, if you prefer to work with it as assoc array, use:

```
$request = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);
```

and access data like:

```
$username = $request['username'];
$password = $request['password'];
```

Comment: Updated answer with more detail